# How to remove the observations (sample) in a biplot (PCA)

Tags: r, graph, pca, biplot

I would like to know how to remove the observations in my biplot (the black numbers in the background in my graph) and only keep the red arrows (variables).

This is my biplot:
biplot(x=pca, choices=1:2) [image]

Comment: please provide a reproducible example using `dput(data)`.

Comment: Did you check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20194526/labeling-points-in-a-biplot ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following for xlabs:

biplot(pca, xlabs=c(rep("", nrow(data))

Comment: I don't think they were trying to remove axis labels—they're trying to remove the observation labels

Answer (score 1):

You could change the color of the labels to white:

```r
biplot(pca, col = c("white", "deeppink3"))
```

Comment: This deletes the figure frame line too.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't fully eliminate them, but using `cex = 0.001` (or some small number like that) will make them so small you barely see them, thus making your plot and arrows much more readable.

```r
biplot(x=pca, choices=1:2, cex = 0.001)
```

If you need to see the names of the arrows, you might want to try `cex = .5` or so.